# Move all files from S3 bucket to Glacier Deep Archive excluding a list of files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket with a lot of files and I need to move all of them to **Glacier Deep Archive**
excluding a list of files that I need keep in their current storage class.

What is the best way to do it?

I used the following:

```
aws s3 cp s3://Bucket_Name/*.mp4 s3://Bucket_Name/*.mp4 --recursive --storage-class DEEP_ARCHIVE
```

I need to add if the file exist in files.txt (list of files) then keep it in current storage class.

Answer (score 1):

Your current method 'copies' the object to itself while changing the Storage Class. Please note that objects under 128KB is the minimum size for objects in the Glacier Deep Archive storage class, so **small objects might not change class**.

Using the AWS CLI is convenient, but can be difficult to 'exclude' selected files. Instead of using the AWS CLI, you might want to **use an AWS SDK in a language of your choice** (eg boto3 for Python) to make the API calls to Amazon S3. You could then code logic into your script to exclude your list of files.

An alternate method is to [use Amazon S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-copy-object.html) to copy objects while changing storage class. Batch Operations takes a **manifest file** as input that lists all files to 'copy'. The manifest file can be created by using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.

If you are using Batch Operations to change storage class, you could edit the manifest file created by S3 Inventory and **remove the files you do not wish to archive**.